# What is Cervantex?

Tags: cervantex

I found something called "[Cervantex](http://www.cervantex.es/)" here on this plattform. I tried to Google it, but I have one problem - I don't speak Spanish.

So are there anyone who please could tell me, what Cervantex is, and what it could be used to? Thank you in advance.

Comment: spanish speaking TeX user group. http://www.ntg.nl/lug/es.html

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you. Next question: how do I close my question (I can't press an OK sign in commend section) :-)

Comment: btw: Even though not great, the google *translate* feature can get you quite a bit around.

Comment: [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5907)

Comment: I don't think you should close or delete your question. It's about a TeX users group and the explanation of the name is cool :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`CervanTeX`](http://www.cervantex.es/) is the Spanish-speaking group of TeX users.

The name was chosen after the first last name of [`Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra`](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_de_Cervantes) a Spanish writer and author of *Don Quixote*. His influence on the Spanish language is so great that Spanish is often called the language of Cervantes (la lengua de Cervantes).

It's common to refer to Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra as just "Cervantes", which almost has (and almost sounds like) "tex" at the end, so the name was a fortunate combination which evokes and suggests both writers (people who write beautiful texts and, by extension, the art of writing (typography)) and also TeX: a great tool to write.

Comment: Writing TeX code and tilting at windmills! Yay! `:)`